# Calling a swift function right after the closing bracket?

Tags: swift

Given that I can do closures like this

```
var test = { () -> String in
   return "this works"
}()
```

I would imagine you could do something like this

```
func testFunc() {
   let _ = "this doesn't work"
}()
```

But this throws an error - `Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'`

As far as I recall, swift's `func`s are just named closures. Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: In your first example you have an "immediately evaluated closure". The result is a string which is then assigned to the variable. It is not clear to me what you want in the second example.

Comment: I want to call a function right after it's definition, without making it too verbose.

Comment: Perhaps this part of the Swift book helps: *„Closure expressions are a way to write inline closures in a brief, focused syntax“* – You have a closure expression in your first example, but not in a second. A (global) function is a special (named) closure, but not a closure expression.

Comment: Thanks @MartinR I think those two comments definitely warrant an answer post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three types of closures in Swift:

> - Global functions are closures that have a name and do not capture any values.
> - Nested functions are closures that have a name and can capture values from their enclosing function.
> - Closure expressions are unnamed closures written in a lightweight syntax that can capture values from their surrounding context.
>
> ...
>
> Closure expressions are a way to write inline closures in a brief,
>   focused syntax.

(Source: [Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID94.) in the Swift book.)

In your first example:

```
var test = { () -> String in return "this works" }()
```

`{ ... }` is a closure expression. This expression is *evaluated*
with an empty argument list `()`. The result is the string
"this works" which is then assigned to the variable.

Your second example is a global function.
Global functions are (named) closures, but not closure expressions.
There is (as far as I know) no similar way to define a function which 
is immediately evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no syntax that accepts

```
func testFunc() {} ()
```

So it should be

```
func testFunc() {
   let myString = "this works"
}
```

and called

```
func myFunc() {
   testFunc() 
}
```

Comment: Is there any reference you could point to where this is defined, I.e. what is a `func` definition, is it a statement?

Comment: In Swift, every [`declaration` is not `expression`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH33-ID428).

Comment: Always check apple's docs first :) 

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html

Answer (score 0):

`func` defines a function. If you want to call it you need to do so in a separate statement:

```
func testFunc() {
  let _ = "this doesn't work"
}

testFunc()
```